# stop ball after hitting object

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm wondering how you would be able to stop a moving ball when it hits an object. I'm using canvas for this.
Here's a little example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>Ball Race</title>
  </head>

  <body>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="200"></canvas>
      <script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;




var circle = function (x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};

var drawRect = function (x, y) {
ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20)
}

var Object = function (xPos, yPos) {
this.x = xPos;
this.y = yPos;
}
// The Ball constructor
var Ball = function () {
  this.x = width / 2;
  this.y = height / 2;
  this.xSpeed = 0;
  this.ySpeed = 0;
  this.radius = 10;
};

// Update the ball's position based on its speed
Ball.prototype.move = function () {
  this.x += this.xSpeed;
  this.y += this.ySpeed;

  if (this.x < 11) {
    this.x = 11;
  } else if (this.x > width - 11) {
    this.x = width - 11;
  } else if (this.y < 11) {
    this.y = 11;
  } else if (this.y > height - 11) {
    this.y = height - 11;
  }
};

// Draw the ball at its current position
Ball.prototype.draw = function () {
  circle(this.x, this.y, 10, true);
};

Object.prototype.draw = function () {
    drawRect(this.x, this.y)
}

//collision types



Object.prototype.checkCollision = function (direction) {
    return (ball.x-ball.radius < this.x + 20)
      && (ball.x+ball.radius > this.x)
      && (ball.y-ball.radius < this.y + 20)
      && (ball.y+ball.radius > this.y)
      ;
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    ball.draw();
    object1.draw();
    object2.draw();
    object3.draw();
    object4.draw();
    object5.draw();

    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
}

function simulate() {
  for (z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
    var prev_ball_x = ball.x;
    var prev_ball_y = ball.y;
    ball.move();
    // handle collision here
    if (object1.checkCollision() || object2.checkCollision() || object3.checkCollision() || object4.checkCollision() || object5.checkCollision()) {
        ball.setDirection('stop');
        // reset ball's position so they do not overlap
        ball.x = prev_ball_x;
        ball.y = prev_ball_y;
    }

  }

  if ($("body").keyup()) {
      ball.setDirection('stop');
    }
}

setInterval(function () {
    // separate drawing and simulating phases
    simulate();
    draw();
}, 30);

// Set the ball's direction based on a string
Ball.prototype.setDirection = function (direction) {
  if (direction === "up") {
     this.xSpeed = 0;
     this.ySpeed = -1;
  } else if (direction === "down") {
     this.xSpeed = 0;
     this.ySpeed = 1;
  } else if (direction === "left") {
     this.xSpeed = -1;
     this.ySpeed = 0;
  } else if (direction === "right") {
     this.xSpeed = 1;
     this.ySpeed = 0;
  } else if (direction === "stop") {
     this.xSpeed = 0;
     this.ySpeed = 0;
  }
};

// Create the ball object
var ball = new Ball();
var object1 = new Object(50, 0);
var object2 = new Object(50, 20);
var object3 = new Object(50, 40);
var object4 = new Object(50, 60);
var object5 = new Object(50, 80);


// An object to convert keycodes into action names
var keyActions = {
  32: "stop",
  37: "left",
  38: "up",
  39: "right",
  40: "down"
};

// The keydown handler that will be called for every keypress
$("body").keydown(function (event) {
  var direction = keyActions[event.keyCode];
  ball.setDirection(direction);
});



       </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

I know could set the speed to 0, but the setInterval would update it automaticaly to move again. How would I solve this into making the ball stop?

Comment: *I know could set the speed to 0, but the setInterval would update it automaticaly to move again.* I don't see why would it

Comment: Oh, it works but then I cant move it again. It just stops there for like 2 seconds which i dontwant

Comment: That is because the two objects remain overlapping, so the speed will always get cleared. Try positioning the ball after collision so they are not overlapping.

Comment: any hints on doing that?

Comment: It's hard because there are multiple sides to consider

Comment: Take a look at my answer, and please don't be so impatient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the speed to 0 on collision. But note that the objects will remain overlapping, so the collision check will keep setting speed back to 0 even when the user tries to move the ball.

I would also merge the two intervals into one, as the second one is doing a lot of 
unnecessary work.

This is the first big step to take when you are writing a physics engine. Fortunately here only the ball is moving, and is not really based on physics, so we can do some "hack" here by repositioning the ball into non-overlapping position on collision.

```
Object.prototype.checkCollision = function (direction) {
    var colx = (ball.x-ball.radius<this.x&&ball.x+ball.radius>this.x)||(ball.x-ball.radius<this.x+20&&ball.x+ball.radius>this.x+20);
    var coly = (ball.y-ball.radius<this.y&&ball.y+ball.radius>this.y)||(ball.y-ball.radius<this.y+20&&ball.y+ball.radius>this.y+20);

    // it really just checks but takes no action
    return colx&&coly;
}

// ...

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    ball.draw();
    object.draw();
    drawLives();

    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
}

function simulate() {
    var prev_ball_x = ball.x;
    var prev_ball_y = ball.y;
    ball.move();
    // handle collision here
    if (object.checkCollision()) {
        ball.setDirection('stop');
        // reset ball's position so they do not overlap
        ball.x = prev_ball_x;
        ball.y = prev_ball_y;
    }
}

setInterval(function () {
    // separate drawing and simulating phases
    simulate();
    draw();
}, 30);
```

#### EDIT:

Fixed the errors in `checkCollision` by rewriting it from scratch.

```
Object.prototype.checkCollision = function (direction) {
    return (ball.x-ball.radius < this.x + 20)
      && (ball.x+ball.radius > this.x)
      && (ball.y-ball.radius < this.y + 20)
      && (ball.y+ball.radius > this.y)
      ;
}
```

When approaching from the top there is a gap because the ball gets repositioned into it's position in the previous frame. You can do better by doing proper repositioning.

> It's hard because there are multiple sides to consider

Yes, indeed it is. That's why I suggested this "move to previous position" hack.

You can make this hacky approach look better by takink more little steps. You can set ball.speed to 1 instead of 5, and execute `simulate` in a for loop five times.

#### EDIT: full code after changes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>Ball Race</title>
  </head>

  <body>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="200"></canvas>
      <script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
var lives = 3;

var drawLives = function () {
    ctx.font = "20px Courier";
    ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
    ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";
    ctx.fillText("Lives left: " + lives, 10, 10);
  };

var circle = function (x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};

var drawRect = function (x, y) {
ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20)
}

var Object = function () {
this.x = width / 4;
this.y = height / 4;
}
// The Ball constructor
var Ball = function () {
  this.x = width / 2;
  this.y = height / 2;
  this.xSpeed = 0;
  this.ySpeed = 0;
  this.radius = 10;
};

// Update the ball's position based on its speed
Ball.prototype.move = function () {
  this.x += this.xSpeed;
  this.y += this.ySpeed;

  if (this.x < 11) {
    this.x = 11;
  } else if (this.x > width - 11) {
    this.x = width - 11;
  } else if (this.y < 11) {
    this.y = 11;
  } else if (this.y > height - 11) {
    this.y = height - 11;
  }
};

// Draw the ball at its current position
Ball.prototype.draw = function () {
  circle(this.x, this.y, 10, true);
};

Object.prototype.draw = function () {
    drawRect(this.x, this.y)
}

//collision types



Object.prototype.checkCollision = function (direction) {
    return (ball.x-ball.radius < this.x + 20)
      && (ball.x+ball.radius > this.x)
      && (ball.y-ball.radius < this.y + 20)
      && (ball.y+ball.radius > this.y)
      ;
}


// Set the ball's direction based on a string
Ball.prototype.setDirection = function (direction) {
  if (direction === "up") {
     this.xSpeed = 0;
     this.ySpeed = -1;
  } else if (direction === "down") {
     this.xSpeed = 0;
     this.ySpeed = 1;
  } else if (direction === "left") {
     this.xSpeed = -1;
     this.ySpeed = 0;
  } else if (direction === "right") {
     this.xSpeed = 1;
     this.ySpeed = 0;
  } else if (direction === "stop") {
     this.xSpeed = 0;
     this.ySpeed = 0;
  }
};

// Create the ball object
var ball = new Ball();
var object = new Object();
// An object to convert keycodes into action names
var keyActions = {
  32: "stop",
  37: "left",
  38: "up",
  39: "right",
  40: "down"
};

// The keydown handler that will be called for every keypress
$("body").keydown(function (event) {
  var direction = keyActions[event.keyCode];
  ball.setDirection(direction);
});

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    ball.draw();
    object.draw();
    drawLives();

    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
}

function simulate() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var prev_ball_x = ball.x;
      var prev_ball_y = ball.y;
      ball.move();
      // handle collision here
      if (object.checkCollision()) {
          ball.setDirection('stop');
          // reset ball's position so they do not overlap
          ball.x = prev_ball_x;
          ball.y = prev_ball_y;
      }
    }
}

setInterval(function () {
    // separate drawing and simulating phases
    simulate();
    draw();
}, 30);

       </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

#### EDIT:

Add `$("body").keyup(function (event) { ball.setDirection('stop'); });` to stop at keydown

Comment: wait is this all of the script?what do i replace?

Comment: replace `Object.prototype.checkCollision`, remove all `setInterval`s, add `draw` and `simulate`, and pray

Comment: Ok, so it worked pretty well but there were two problems. One, when you go exactly in the middle under the bottom of the object, it goes right through

Comment: two, the top collision part stop about 3 pixels apart from the edge

Comment: you test and see how it goes

Comment: Thanks! I don't see the difference in adding the for loop and changing the speed, but the checkCollision change made it look a whole lot better

Comment: Try it and you will see. I'll post full code immediately

Comment: Btw is there a function that detects keydown and keyup? I now want it to stop when i release a key

Comment: What do you think `$("body").keydown` does? I'm pretty sure there is `keyup` as well

Comment: Dang. Would I have to change the whole direction thing?

Comment: Simplest, but not best is to add: `$("body").keyup(function (event) { ball.setDirection('stop'); });`. You didn't write a single line of this code yourself did you.

Comment: @Cool123 no it didn't

Comment: I suspect you removed the for loop around simulate, but set speed to 1

Comment: there i changed my question code to what i have now

Comment: wait, why did you redefine `Object`? I'm sure you could have used `object` or any other variable name. `Object` is a built in prototype/class. It should not be redefined.

Comment: @ahitt6345 he does know nothing about the original Object, he just created a new class in the scope hiding the original Object. The original is still in self.Object

Comment: @Cool123 You failed to copy a single line of code. How should I help you if you didn't even read your own source before posting a question?

Comment: Didn't see it whoops xD

Comment: just wondering, you know I'm starting to make a racing game. How would I make an animation that the background including the objects are moving to the left like something real